# Twit is not subscribing to stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I have this code, that is supposed to stream whatever Elon Musk is posting:

```
const twitter = new Twit({`consumer and access tokens provided`});

var stream = twitter.stream('statuses/filter', { track: '@elonmusk' });

stream.on('tweet', (tweet) => {
  console.log(tweet);
});

stream.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

But, whenever I run it, I get

```
Error: Bad Twitter streaming request: 404
    at exports.makeTwitError (Documents/nCommBot/nCommentTwitter/node_modules/twit/lib/helpers.js:74:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (Documents/nCommBot/nCommentTwitter/node_modules/twit/lib/streaming-api-connection.js:96:29)
    at Request.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Documents/nCommBot/nCommentTwitter/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: null,
  allErrors: [],
  twitterReply: '',
  statusCode: 404
}
```

Honestly, I have no idea what is wrong with this one....

Answer (score 0):

There is no User stream anymore! Twitter has removed it entirely. This is why you get a 404 error.

[image]

[Twitter announcement](https://twittercommunity.com/t/details-and-what-to-expect-from-the-api-deprecations-this-week-on-august-16-2018/110746)